# did not redirect logged in page in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I am working with laravel 5.2 and use auth command to develop log/register system and Lartrust admin panel. then now when I logged with the system logging page did not move to `localhost:8000/home` page. it is redirect to again `welcome.blade.php` page. how can I redirect My logged in page to localhost:8000/home My routes.php is

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your login controller change redirectTo '/' to '/home';

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{


    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

}
```